Is it possible to provide letters of recommendation later in the process because of an error when inserting them in the system?
For an application to a postdoctoral position in the US, I made a mistake when inserting the emails of my referees. Could the committee take into account my application, and then ask me to submit the recommendation later in the process?

They might. They might not. But only they know. Ask.

At least at some places the committee will only see application packets that are complete - the admins won't forward incomplete packages. And is a committee even involved in a postdoc application?

There should be a person named in the advertisement, or at least an email listed that you can contact with questions.  This is a reasonable question to email them about.

This will depend entirely on the institution and department where you are applying. I know in my department at my institution the answer is "yes", and in fact we've had letters of recommendation added to interview packages that were originally sent out a week beforehand, on the morning that we were conducting interviews.
So ask them. the worst that could happen is they say definitively say "no", and at least then you'll know.
